# VBA not pasting into empty row in table

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to copy and paste rows that meet a certain criteria into a table in another workbook.

My VBA works perfectly except for it pastes in the empty cell below the table. Not in the empty cells below the headers within the table.

PS. I know using select is generally frowned upon, but I needed to use fairly basic syntax so that if the next person needs to modify this and is unfamiliar with VBA they can.

```
Sub Export()

Sheets("Export Format").Select

Cells(13, "D").Calculate

        With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))  'reference its column A:G cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty one in column "A"
            
            .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>0" ' filter referenced cells on 6th column with everything but "0" content
            
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 1 Then
                
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ' copy filtered cells skipping headers
                
                With Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Z:\Tracking\Database.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1") 'open wanted workbook and reference its wanted sheet
                    
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone _
                    , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 'paste filtered cells in referenced sheet from ist column A first empty cell after last not empty one
                    
                    .Parent.Close True 'Save and closes referenced workbook
                
                End With
                
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
            End If
        
        End With
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets("Export Format").ShowAllData 'Clears Filters
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        Sheets("Export Format").Select 'Brings back to Main request sheet
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is the table empty ?

Comment: Yes, the table is empty. I have added a picture of the database for reference on what's happening.

Comment: Presumably Region is column A, are you sure that blank cell doesn't contain hidden spaces ?

Comment: Correct, region is column A and I've cleared the contents of the row so there's nothing in them.

Comment: Seems like xlup won't enter the table,The proper way would be to reference the table object, do know the table's name ? If you know the table is empty then I guess removing the `.Offset(1, 0)` might work (but confuse a subsequent maintainer !)

Comment: I didn’t even think about that. The table’ name is just “Table1” I haven’t bothered to rename it yet. Do you know how I could go about referencing the table? I could put a note in there to explain it to the next maintainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a property of the table such as [InsertRowRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.insertrowrange)

```vb
Sub Export()

    Const DBFILE = "Z:\Tracking\Database.xlsx"
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbDB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject
    Dim rngFilter As Range, x, rng As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Export Format")
    
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, ws.Columns(1))
    If x <= 1 Then
        ws.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' set filter range
    With ws
       .Range("D13").Calculate
       ' column A:L cells from row 1 (header)
       ' down to last not empty one in column "A"
       Set rngFilter = .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    ' open wanted workbook and reference its wanted sheet
    Set wbDB = Workbooks.Open(DBFILE)
    With wbDB.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set tbl = .ListObjects("Table1")
        If tbl.InsertRowRange Is Nothing Then
           Set rng = tbl.ListRows.Add.Range
        Else
           Set rng = tbl.InsertRowRange
        End If
    End With

    ' filter on 6th column with everything but "0" content
    With rngFilter

        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>0"
        ' copy filtered cells skipping headers
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        'paste filtered cells in referenced sheet
        'from ist column A first empty cell after last not empty one
        rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
       
    End With

    wbDB.Close True 'Save and closes referenced workbook
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Select 'Brings back to Main request sheet
    MsgBox "Ended"
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly!